# get timezone abbreviation for arbitrary time in arbitrary locale

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a UTC time and a locale name in Postgres.  I want to get the local timezone abbreviation at that specific time (the time matters since, for e.g. the `America/New_York` timezone, the abbreviation might be EST or EDT depending on whether the time falls within DST).

Ideally I'd use `pg_timezone_names` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html) to map the timezone name to an abbreviation, but `pg_timezone_names` is based on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, not on the time I'm concerned with.